# Issue launching Wing from C#

Tags: c#, python

I have this snippet of code:

```
void wing()
{
    Process wing = new Process();
    wing.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    wing.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Wing IDE 4.0\\bin\\wing.exe";
    wing.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\Desktop\\hello.py";
    wing.Start(); 
}
```

Every time time I run this snippet, my program really opens wing with the file, but strange thing is that the path for file in wing is: `C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects...`. How could it be? Also, I can't see code inside `hello.py`. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting double quotes around the filename i.e. @"""" + "C:\....your file" + @""""